# How to inherit NSManagedObject?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I've read that is bad to inherit NSManagedObject in core data because it creates a single table with all properties.

What is the best practice if all entities have common properties ?
updated_at, created_at, deleted... normal... Txs for help ! :)

Comment: All entities in a Core Data model inherits from NSManagedObject so I don't understand your first sentence. For your question I think it is best to add the properties to all entities that needs them or have them in a separate entity that other entities has a one-to-one relationship with, all depending on the situation of course

Comment: I mean inherit MyEntity from MyAbstractEntity (that of course inherits from NSManagedObject)
Where all my common properties are in MyAbstractEntity...
I really have to copy all my common properties in all my entities this is weird!

Comment: Inheriting is not recommended in Core Data and as I wrote you can use composition as well